# How to get the webpage title using JavaScript executor

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, junit4

I am new bee of the automation testing. On my code, I am using the JavaScript on my Selenium automation test script (on using the JUnit). I am trying to find the current window title:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
js = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;

driver.get(//passed url);

//after the log in my Org. I execute the command below

//to get the title of the current window I execute the below command        
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('title').innerHTML;");
```

> But the above command will return the answer as the **null** instant of
>   getting the title of the window. So does anyone know what's wrong with
>   my command?

But I get the title of the window on executing on the console log of the page. So I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Thanks.

Mohan Raj S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title').innerHTML
```

to:

return document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML

in code it will be:

```
js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;");
```

getElementsByTagName returns array of elements. So we need to pass the index value.

Web driver interface provides get title method. It is very simple.

```
String title=driver.getTitle();
System.out.println("Title is" + title);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also give the index as the "0" as per your command but I got the same answer as null for the title :(.

Comment: have checked the dom qurey in browser console?

Comment: is title tag there in your page source?

Comment: I give the command as the browser console as following
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
it's give the title

Comment: sorry you can add return word as  return document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML. updated my answer.

Comment: Means I give the command like 
js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;"); 
Okay I will try..

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this also

```
function titleCheck() {
        promise = driver.getTitle();
        promise.then(function(title) {
            console.log("The title is: " + title);
        });
    }
```

reference: https://blog.testproject.io/2018/03/08/selenium-javascript-best-practices/

though their var test- stuff doesn't work for me I had to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 

String text = js.executeScript("return document.title;").toString();
```